# MySQL conditional select when a inner join involves

Tags: mysql

I am working on a project where we develop a tourist app. Some items are add to the system as
advertisements (Hotels, Night clubs) and some items add as useful information (beaches,national parks)

I have a table called items.

items

```
id | category_id | name                | is_payment 
1  | 1           | hotel califonia     | 1          
2  | 1           | hotel hilton        | 1          
3  | 2           | Yala national park  | 0          
4  | 2           | Kumana national park| 0
```

here category_id refers the categories table.

categories

```
id | name           | type
1  | Hotels         | commercial
2  | National parks | non-commercial
```

I want to select all the items from the item table.

But if it's a commercial item I need to check whether payment is made or not before display to the end users.

I don't have to show anything what I did up-to now.
I though the CASE function and IF function as well. But I don't know how to link those with this case study.
I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: So do you want a query to do this right? Or anything else required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I below query you can I am taking all non-commercial item Or if it is commercial then I am checking payment is also done using and operator.

```
SELECT i.*
FROM items i
JOIN categories c 
ON i.category_id = c.id
WHERE c.type != 'commercial' 
OR (c.type = 'commercial' AND i.is_payment = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for another query other than the above answer...

```
select a.* from items a join categories b on a.category_id=b.id and b.type='commercial' and a.is_payment=1
union all
select a.* from items a join categories b on a.category_id=b.id and b.type<>'commercial';
```